# How to check that group has a value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by

For example, I have a table tbl like

```
values
10
20
30
40
```

on this table by the condition I have GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT ???
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY values
```

I need to check that group has some value, for example 30

**UPD:**
In real task a have a table with many columns and other operations on them and in one column i need to check whether value in every group of this column.

**UPD2:**
I need something like this:

```
select 
min(created_timestamp),
max(resource_id),
max(price),
CASE WHEN event_type has (1704 or 1701 or 1703) THEN return found value END
CASE WHEN event_type has (1707) THEN return 1707 END
from subscriptions
group by guid
```

Comment: Does your table really have one column?

Comment: no, it have more than one column

Comment: Then, give us a few rows of your table and the expected output of the query.

Comment: no. rows with the same guid has different event_types, but with one guid may be only one from (1704 or 1701 or 1703) and if in group exist event_type with 1704, the same guid may contain 1707

Comment: Then, give us a few rows of your table and the expected output of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    MIN(created_timestamp),
    MAX(resource_id),
    MAX(price),
    MIN(CASE WHEN event_type IN (1704, 1701, 1703) 
                 THEN found_value 
             WHEN event_type = 1707 
                 THEN 1707 
                 ELSE NULL 
        END)
FROM subscriptions
GROUP BY guid ;
```

Comment: I did not know that it is possible inside the group functions, write the conditions. That's all I need

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what you have in the select clause .. but if you want to see the values also in the out put when you run the group by query try this

select function(), values from tbl group by values

function() -- could be any function like -- count or sum

and if you want only specific to value 30 .. then add a where clause values = 30.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use group by clause if your aim is to find if some value exists.
Use this method if you also consider the performance.

```
SELECT DECODE (COUNT(1),0,'Not Exist','Yes has some values')
FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM tbl
               WHERE VALUES='&Your_Value_To_Check'
               )
```

Comment: That's a complicated way of writing `WHERE values = 30` (where I'm substituting 30 as the 'value to check').

Comment: Not very complicated .This sql checks and gives  the verbal answer.